# ATL COM - EnumWindows callback function not working with IDispatch::Invoke

Tags: c++, callback, dispatch

I am trying to implement a wrapper function for `EnumWindows` API function to be included in my wrapper dll, so it can be used with many scripting languages.

First of all, I had to test it using VBScript. I implemented a wrapper function and a callback function for `EnumWindows` with the help of my useful researches, but it is not working as I want.

Here is the code I currently have:

*Wrapper functions for `EnumWindows` and `EnumWindowsProc` callback:*

```
BOOL CALLBACK EnumWindowsProc(__in HWND hWnd, __in LPARAM lParam) {

    LPENUMWINDOWSPARAMS pewParams;
    VARIANT vhWnd, vResult; HRESULT HR = S_OK;

    VariantInit(&vhWnd);
    VariantInit(&vResult);

    vhWnd.vt = VT_I4;
    vhWnd.lVal = (LONG)(LONG_PTR)hWnd;

    pewParams = reinterpret_cast<LPENUMWINDOWSPARAMS>(lParam);
    // ^ PASSING MY PARAMETERS THROUGH LPARAM

    CComVariant varArgs[2] = { &vResult, &vhWnd };
    DISPPARAMS Parameters = { &varArgs[0], NULL, 2, 0 };

    pewParams->DISPATCH->Invoke(0, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &Parameters, &vResult, NULL, NULL);
    // ^ I SUSPECT SOMETHING IS WRONG WITH THIS INVOKE METHOD. BUT IT RETURNS S_OK.

    if (vResult.vt != VT_BOOL) { HR = DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH; }

    pewParams->CallbackResult.vt = VT_ERROR;
    pewParams->CallbackResult.scode = HR;

    if (HR == S_OK)
        return (vResult.boolVal == VARIANT_TRUE ? TRUE : FALSE);
    else
        return FALSE;
}

STDMETHODIMP CWinAPI::WinAPI_EnumWindows(VARIANT EnumFunc, int lParam, int *Result) {

    ENUMWINDOWSPARAMS ewParams; HRESULT HR = S_OK;

    switch (EnumFunc.vt)
    {
        case VT_DISPATCH:
            ewParams.DISPATCH = EnumFunc.pdispVal;
            break;

        case VT_VARIANT | VT_BYREF:
            if (EnumFunc.pvarVal->vt == VT_DISPATCH) { ewParams.DISPATCH = EnumFunc.pvarVal->pdispVal; }
            break;

        default: return DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH;
    }

    ewParams.lParam = reinterpret_cast<LPVARIANT>(&lParam);

    *Result = (int)EnumWindows(EnumWindowsProc, reinterpret_cast<LPARAM>(&ewParams));

    HR = ewParams.CallbackResult.scode;

    return HR;
}
```

*`ENUMWINDOWSPARAMS` structure:*

```
typedef struct tagENUMWINDOWSPARAMS {
    LPDISPATCH DISPATCH;
    LPVARIANT lParam;
    VARIANT CallbackResult;
} ENUMWINDOWSPARAMS, *PENUMWINDOWSPARAMS, *LPENUMWINDOWSPARAMS;
```

Here is the testing VBScript I am currently using:

```
Dim WINAPI: Set WINAPI = WScript.CreateObject("WinAPIWrapperLib.WINAPI")

Function EnumWindowsProc(HWND, lParam)
    WScript.Echo "Handle to the window: 0x" + CStr(UCase(Hex(HWND)))
    EnumWindowsProc = True
End Function

Dim Result: Result = WINAPI.WinAPI_EnumWindows(GetRef("EnumWindowsProc"), 0)
WScript.Echo "EnumWindows returned " + CStr(Result)
```

One thing works, `EnumWindows` is returning `True`.
But, instead what I expect, I am not getting handles of windows echoed.
And when I call `GetLastError`, it returns `ERROR_SUCCESS`.

Thanks in advance for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem, nothing special done, it's only a small change:

Changed `varArgs`'s type from `CComVariant` to `VARIANT` like this:

```
VARIANT varArgs[2] = { vResult, vhWnd };
```

Changed `DISPPARAMS` as below:

```
DISPPARAMS Parameters = {};
Parameters.cArgs = 2;
Parameters.rgvarg = varArgs;
```

`Invoke` method is still the same:

```
pewParams->DISPATCH->Invoke(0, IID_NULL, LOCALE_USER_DEFAULT, DISPATCH_METHOD, &Parameters, &vResult, NULL, NULL);
```

Any good suggestions are further appreciated.